# Get Credit Card Approval in Sabre Soap API

Tags: xml, sabre

I called the Sabre SOAP API request CreditVerificationLLSRQ to get credit card approval response, here I am getting some error in the response. Can anyone suggest me to resolve this error. My request is following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:v3="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Security>

         <sec:BinarySecurityToken>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader>
         <mes:From>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:From>
         <mes:To>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>XXXX</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Service mes:type="sabreXML">sabreXML</mes:Service>
         <mes:Action>CreditVerificationLLSRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>00000</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>233</mes:Timestamp>

         </mes:MessageData>

         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <mes:Description xml:lang="en-US">Testing</mes:Description>
         <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>

   <CreditVerificationRQ Version="2.2.0" >
    <Credit>
        <CC_Info>
            <PaymentCard AirlineCode="F9" Code="123" ExpireDate="2017-04" Number="4111111111111111" />
        </CC_Info>
        <ItinTotalFare>
            <TotalFare Amount="565.36" CurrencyCode="USD" />
        </ItinTotalFare>
    </Credit>
</CreditVerificationRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm getting the response is the following with error:

```
<soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.Validation</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
               <stl:Error timeStamp="2016-12-21T06:58:35-06:00" type="Validation">
                  <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                     <stl:Message>cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'CreditVerificationRQ'.</stl:Message>
                     <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
                  </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
               </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the namespace declarations. Try adding xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" in the RQ header.